# Custom templates for Rails 6.1 jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `lib/templates/erb/scaffold/**.html.erb.tt` files and I'm trying to customise the files output by Jbuilder (because I need a standardised name. No matter what I try, I'm unable to get my own templates to be used, instead of the defaults which. I've tried putting them in `lib/templates/jbuilder/scaffold`, but as far as I can tell from the jbuilder gem it [only ever looks at it's own template folder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/lib/generators/rails/jbuilder_generator.rb#L9).

Halp!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd already tried `lib/templates/rails/jbuilder/index.json.jbuilder.tt` but it appears not.

That path seemed to fix it.